# How do I get emacs to insert text into an arbitrary file?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'm trying to create a function that inserts text into an arbitrary file without switching to that file's buffer.

I know this could be done with echo, but is there a way to do it using only elisp?

Comment: For appending to files, check the functions `append-to-file` and `write-region` on the elisp reference (info - Elisp - Writing to files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this function:

```
(defun append-string-to-file (string filename)
  "Appends STRING to FILENAME."
  (interactive)
  (append-to-file string nil filename))
```

Comment: How is this expected to work interactively? (And why not just use `append-to-file`, which does?)

Answer (score 2):

You need to make a buffer current to do pretty much anything with its content. Making a buffer current is related to the Lisp interpreter, it doesn't involve displaying the buffer in a window. The basic primitives are `set-buffer` to set the buffer for subsequent operations and `save-excursion` to execute a piece of code and restore the current buffer afterwards.

There are a number of macros called `with-SOMETHING` to execute code with different settings (such as the current buffer) and restore the settings when the code exits (for any reason, whether it's normal exit or an exception).

```
(with-current-buffer "name-of-file-that's-already-open"
  (goto-char 42)
  (insert "hello"))
```

If you want to open the file and close it when you're done, there's no `with-` macro in the standard library. (Warning: typed directly in the browser.)

```
(save-excursion
  (let (buf)
    (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (setq buf (find-file-noselect "filename"))
        (when buf
          (goto-char 42)
          (insert "hello")))
      (if buf (kill-buffer buf))))
```